# installing z3 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu-18.04, z3

I want to run a program that uses z3 on Ubuntu.
I tried to install z3 on Ubuntu 18.04 and received a success message, but although z3 is installed correctly, I get the following error when running the program.

```
 For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{GAC}".
          Considered "Microsoft.Z3", which was not found in the GAC.
          For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
          Considered treating "Microsoft.Z3" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "bin/x64/Release/".
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
```

```
PolicySynthesis.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
Synthesize.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
```

I tried many times and did not succeed. Please help me